# Retrofit - use response class with inheritance

Tags: android, generics, retrofit

I'm trying make reuse of single retrofit api call by inherit from a base response class.

However I'm not able to do it.

I will try to make myself clear with example (It's not a concrete scenario. I'm just trying to figure out the main idea):

Having this response objects and api service:

```
public class UserDetailsResponse
{
    private int userId;
}

public class ExtendedUserDetailsResponse extends UserDetailsResponse
{
    private int userAdditionalId;
}

interface APIService
{
   @GET("/UserDetails/")
   Call<UserDetailsResponse> getUserDetails(@Query("id") String userId);
}
```

Is there a way of using getUserDetails api with ExtendedUserDetailsResponse object?

This one gives me compilation error:

```
   mService.getUserDetails("123").enqueue(new Callback<ExtendedUserDetailsResponse>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ExtendedUserDetailsResponse> call, Response<ExtendedUserDetailsResponse> response)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ExtendedUserDetailsResponse> call, Throwable t)
            {

            }
        });
```

How can I solve this? or at least something similar to this, without using a new api call for the specific derived class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting compilation error because you are using the wrong callback object:

Just change this line:

```
Call<UserDetailsResponse> getUserDetails(@Query("id") String userId);
```

to

```
Call<ExtendedUserDetailsResponse> getUserDetails(@Query("id") String userId);
```

Or depending on the response change the object in the callback

Note that `ExtendedUserDetailsResponse` will have `userId` so you can use `ExtendedUserDetailsResponse` even if the server returns object of type `UserDetailsResponse` or `ExtendedUserDetailsResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because ExtendedUserDetailsResponse is a UserDetailsResponse, however, UserDetailsResponse is not necessarily an ExtendedUserDetailsResponse.

In order to make it generic, sign your method this way

```
Call< ExtendedUserDetailsResponse > getUserDetails(@Query("id") String userId);
```

Then ExtendedUserDetailsResponse will have access to **userId**

Remember to expose userId with getters and setters so that it get parsed.